# Coding Error in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Below is my code ... What I am doing is that I am creating a resource calendar and then I am        counting the no of Events associated with that bt in my spreadsheet I want it only once bt its  gt printed in every column.....
    Secondly Suppose I have two different events and I want to count it individually ..How to do that?

```
function caltest3(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0ArPwl7-RVTW4dFVaa204X1dXTGtBS0pxR2RUR1E4dkE");   //get spreadsheet by id
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);                                            //get active spreadsheet
var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("_qMPDrbdlAAEgLlc2wfBUw@bmsinfoline.com");      //get calendar by id
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();                                        //get acive sheet
 var d1 = new Date("January 1, 2013");                                               //get dates
var d2 = new Date("July 13, 2013");  
var events = CalendarApp.getEvents(d1, d2);

for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {

 var details=[[events[i].getLocation(), events.length]];
  // var details = [[events.length]];
 var row = i+1;
var range=sheet.getRange(row+1,1,1,2);

 range.setValues(details);
Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events.length);
```

}
}

Comment: please try to re-formulate your question, It is not very clear what issue you are having ...

Comment: hi  @Sergeinsas..My question is ...Suppose in my google apps calendar I have created to resources ..while in my script I want to assign dm in a array suppose calld EventsArray ..Tell me how will I connect this EventsArray elements to my resources..So that As I select EventsArray in output it automatically knows that it has two resiurces named this and this

Comment: Where do you 'select' the events array ?

Comment: That is I want to know ... See what I did was I created three Resources in my google calendar ....these three resource are suppose Room 1 room 2 room3 ...and now room1 and room two are in building A and room3 in building 2..What I want that in GUI I select a building and a start and end date and then in spreadsheet It show me  like no of bookings like  if I have selected and A so it should show me no of bookings for Room1 and Room 2

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325025/google-calendar-and-google-apps-script-and-spreadsheet/17331830#17331830) to see how to retrieve events from a calendar and write it properly to a spreadsheet.

From there I would suggest you sort the array on the "ressource" column and sow intermediate results whenever the content of this column changes. This way you will have a clear view of all the events correspondinf to each ressource.
The array sort is quite  straightforward and goes like this :

```
dataArray.sort(function(x,y){
  var xp = x[col-1];// col is the index number of the column where you put the ressource data
  var yp = y[col-1];
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;
  });
```

Of course you can also do that after writing to the sheet if you want to be able to have different data presentation... why not create a new sheet for every presentation ...
up to you ;-)